# can we convert android app script into web app?

Tags: android, web, web-applications

i want to know that can we convert the android app script into a web app?
if anyone knows about it please tell me. before answering my question I would tell you that I know that we can convert a web app into Andriod app but I don't know can we convert an android app script into a web app or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to convert native android application to web app.
In case you want to create application for different platforms you have to use multiplatform frameworks like cordova.